# ngAnimate causes element.css ('display','block') failure when reloading the route

Tags: angularjs, routes, jquery-animate

This example is injected into the ngAnimate.
First, you need to visit this test page like "/#/test/1" , 3 seconds after the modified $location.path ('/test/2'), the controller is re loaded,but the floating layer can not be displayed (box.css('display', 'block') failure).
If you do not inject ngAnimate, everythings is ok, the floating layer can be displayed.
I don't know what's going on, it's a bug ngAnimate?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .popup {
        position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(36,36,36,.96); top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1;
    }
    .popup .context .hd {
        font-size: 32px; color:#FFF; text-align: center;
    }
    .popup .close {
        font-size: 32px; color:#999; text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper" ng-view></div>
    <script src="angular_1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="angular-animate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

template demo.html

```
route : <span style="color:red; font-size: 32px;">{{id}}</span>
<input type="button" pop-window-open ng-click="openPopWindow()" style="width:200px; height: 50px;" value="open window">
<section class="popup" id="popWindow" style="display: none;">
    <div class="context">
        <div class="hd">pop window</div>
        <div class="bd"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="close" pop-window-close ng-click="closePopWindow()">close</div>
</section>
```

javascript:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'youyuApp.controllers', 'youyuApp.directives'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/test/:id', {
                templateUrl : 'demo.html',
                controller : 'ctrl1'
            });
    }]);
angular.module('youyuApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', '$location', '$timeout', '$routeParams',
        function($scope, $location, $timeout, $routeParams) {
            $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
            $timeout(function() {
                $location.path('/test/2');
            }, 3000);
    }]);

angular.module('youyuApp.directives', [])
    .directive('popWindowOpen', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var box = angular.element(document.getElementById('popWindow'));
                scope.openPopWindow = function() {
                    box.css('display', 'block');
                };
            }
        }
    })
    .directive('popWindowClose', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope : true,
            link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var box = angular.element(document.getElementById('popWindow'));
                scope.closePopWindow = function() {
                    box.css('display', 'none');
                };
            }
        }
    })
```